# display current button of multiple set of buttons

Tags: javascript, php

I have a set of buttons where a `js` code selected the current button to display it differently.

What I would like to do is to have two sets of buttons, in which I can interact with the buttons in the different sets independently.

Like select the button "1" on the first set and "2" on the second set. In a perfect world, I would like to have only one function in `js` to do it for different sets. I don't know how to do it.

My one set of button is like this :

```js
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear about what you want, but I guess this is what you want, I added another button in the following snippet, I change few things:

1. Remove the selector based on the ID and replace it with selector for class name `document.querySelectorAll(".button-set")` via `querySelectorAll()`
2. Loop though the button set (2 element in my snippet), and change the selector of the button for `active` class to the current div `id` since it is unique and allow us to target a specific set.
3. Add unique `ID` value for div group or set.

```js
var sets = document.querySelectorAll(".button-set");

sets.forEach((el, i) => {
  btns = el.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var button = document.querySelector(`#${el.id} .active`);
      button.className = button.className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="button-set">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
<br />
<div id="myDIV2" class="button-set">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was what i was looking for !

Answer (score 2):

your question is unclear, is this answer a good one ?

this is about JS event delegation,
you should also use `classList.toggle()`, which allows to directly include the test

```js
const DivAllButtons = document.getElementById('All-buttons')

DivAllButtons.onclick = ({target : clicked_Element }) =>
  {
  if (!clicked_Element.matches('button.btn')) return

  clicked_Element.parentNode
  .querySelectorAll('button.btn')
  .forEach( bt =>
    {
    bt.classList.toggle( 'active', bt===clicked_Element ) 
    }); 
  }
```

```css
#All-buttons > div { 
  margin: 1em; 
  }
.btn {
  border           : none;
  outline          : none;
  padding          : 10px 16px;
  background-color : #f1f1f1;
  cursor           : pointer;
  font-size        : 18px;
  }
.active, 
.btn:hover {
  background-color : #666;
  color            : white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="All-buttons">
  <div>
    <button class="btn">1</button> <button class="btn active">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button> <button class="btn">4</button> <button class="btn">5</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn">1</button> <button class="btn active">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button> <button class="btn">4</button> <button class="btn">5</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn">1</button> <button class="btn active">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button> <button class="btn">4</button> <button class="btn">5</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn">1</button> <button class="btn active">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button> <button class="btn">4</button> <button class="btn">5</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn">1</button> <button class="btn active">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button> <button class="btn">4</button> <button class="btn">5</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @you2525  I have added more sets of buttons, who works with the same JS code. My solution is really much lighter than Ma'moun othman's - who does the same as mine